# Y graphical layout doesn't show sometimes on eclipse &MOTODev ?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

my graphical layout doesn't appear on my eclipse window at same time main.xml can visible and editable also,what happening on XML file.
    i tried to close xml and opened again ,but still it continues..any permanent solution on this.
    this happened on eclipse &MotoDev also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like XML files are being opened by an editor other than the default Android editor. This can be a problem if you are using other plugins that handle XML files.

1. Close all open windows
2. Right click your layout.xml and choose "Open With"
3. Choose "Android Common XML Editor"

[image: Android Common XML Editor in Eclipse or MOTODEV]

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported the project. then make it sure imported project should be in your selected workspace.

or

If you have imported some project from another platform i.e project is made in 2.2 and you have only 4.0, then it will not show you layouts, then you have to download 2.2 sdk for it